# ASPX site errors on same line of C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, error-handling

I have an ASPX site that grabs a screenshot and returns it to me. The site works on Dev server but when moved to Prod I get an error on the same line no matter what (even when blank). Here is my error:
[image]

Here is my code that I am using to make the API request. I set the image url in html to the downloaded file location. It has always worked for me until I migrated to Prod. Dev server and Prod server have same configs and all code has been changed to reflect the migration.

```
protected void Screen_Shot()
    {
        string input = TextBox1.Text;
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            string filename = @"C:\Screen_Shot.jpg";
            string destination = @"http://api.screenshotmachine.com/?key=111111&size=N&url=" + input;
            try{

                client.DownloadFile(destination, filename);
                Image1.Visible = true;
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                Image1.Visible = true;
                Image1.ImageUrl = @"C:\Windows\Temp\screenshot_error.jpg";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try capturing the request through Fiddler. It may help to narrow down.

Comment: It looks like IIS pool using old version of the dll. Did you make sure to recycle it after deployment?

Comment: @Andrei Yes I have refeshed the instance of the website. I also use the dll in other parts of the site that work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to clear the error by cleaning the solution and then rebuilding it. Thanks you guys for all your help.